# l3regex: braced quantifier from variable

Tags: expl3, l3regex

I would like to create a regular expression to be used in expl3 syntax where the integer for the braced quantifier is taken from a variable into which the relevant value has previously been stored.

However, if I try `\d{ \u{l_myint_int} }` as shown in the following MWE, a warning is written to the log saying `Braced quantifier '{' may not be followed by 'u'.`. So, it seems that it is not possible to use `\u` inside a braced quantifier. How could I solve this problem, probably using a workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_myseq_seq

\regex_extract_all:nnN { \d{ 2 } } { 1234 } \l_myseq_seq

x\seq_use:Nn \l_myseq_seq { , }x

\par

\int_new:N \l_myint_int
\int_set:Nn \l_myint_int { 2 }

\regex_extract_all:nnN { \d{ \u{l_myint_int} } } { 1234 } \l_myseq_seq
% Log: LaTeX3 Warning: Braced quantifier '{' may not be followed by 'u'.

x\seq_use:Nn \l_myseq_seq { , }x

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The argument to `\u`, in the context of a regex, should be the name of a token list variable; you're using an integer variable.
2. There is no “recursion”: you can't give `\d` a regex to be interpreted.

For the first problem, use a `tl` variable.

For the second problem, use a variant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_myseq_seq

\regex_extract_all:nnN { \d{ 2 } } { 1234 } \l_myseq_seq

x\seq_use:Nn \l_myseq_seq { , }x

\par

\tl_new:N \l_myint_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_myint_tl { 2 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jasper_regex_extract_digit:nnN
 {
  \regex_extract_all:nnN { \d{#1} } { #2 } #3
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jasper_regex_extract_digit:nnN { V }

\jasper_regex_extract_digit:VnN \l_myint_tl { 1234 } \l_myseq_seq

x\seq_use:Nn \l_myseq_seq { , }x

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As to 1): I used `\u` with an integer in a regex, but not as braced quantifier, which worked. Hence, I did not realise that only token lists should be used in this context.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Actually, with the above approach you can use any variable type that makes sense in `V` expansion, so also an `int` variable.